# MemoryError: out of memory

Tags: python, memory

I use the script *pilfer-archive-new.py* from "Gray Hat Hackers Handbook" to download some files from the internet archive. But when I try to download a lot of files (for example some hundred thousand entries found for .pdf) then I get the following error: 
[image]

The source code for the script is listed below:

```
#--
#
# Name: pilfer-archive-new (attempt #2)
# Description: Pilfer Archive.org for files to fuzz. Fixed a few threading issues and organized the code better.
#              It still needs a little bit of work but thread stability is much better. glhf.
# Author(s): level@coresecurity.com
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
# AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
# WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. 
# IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, 
# INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT 
# NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR 
# PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, 
# WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) 
# ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE 
# POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
#
#--



#--
#
# Name: pilfer-archive-new (attempt #2)
# Description: Pilfer Archive.org for files to fuzz. Fixed a few threading issues and organized the code better.
#              It still needs a little bit of work but thread stability is much better. glhf.
# Author(s): level@coresecurity.com
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
# AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
# WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. 
# IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, 
# INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT 
# NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR 
# PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, 
# WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) 
# ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE 
# POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
#
#--



import re, urllib2, socket, json, os, Queue, sys
from threading import Thread

searchQueue,downloadQueue = Queue.Queue(),Queue.Queue()
log=True
debug=False

class Obtain:
    def file_exists(self,path):
        if (os.path.exists("repo/%s" % (path)) == True):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def file_download(self,path):
        file = path.split("/")[-1]
        if (Obtain().file_exists(file) != True):
            data = urllib2.urlopen(path).read()
            if ("<html" not in data):
                fp = open("repo/%s" % (file),"w")
                fp.write(data)
                fp.close()
            if (log == True): print "[*] Wrote %s to file system" % (file)
        return

class Discover:
    def find_available(self,term):
        data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen("https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php?q=%s&mediatype=&rows=1&page=1&output=json&save=no#raw" % (term)).read())
        numFound = data["response"]["numFound"]
        return numFound
    def get_titles(self,term,numFound):
        data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen("https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php?q=%s&mediatype=&rows=%d&page=1&output=json&save=no#raw" % (term,numFound)).read())
        titles = []
        for i in xrange(0,numFound-1):
                        try:
                                if (" " in data["response"]["docs"][i]["title"]):
                                        titles.append(data["response"]["docs"][i]["title"].replace(" ","-"))
                                else:
                                        titles.append(data["response"]["docs"][i]["title"])
            except Exception as e:
                                pass
        return titles[:500]
    def get_locations(self,titles):
        urls = []
        for title in titles:
            try:
                data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen("https://archive.org/details/%s&output=json&callback=IAE.favorite" % (title)).read()[13:-1])
                url = "https://%s%s" % (data["server"],data["dir"])
                urls.append(url)
            except Exception as e:
                if (debug == True): print "[*] DEBUG -- Function: Discover().get_locations('%s') Exception: %s" % (title,e)
                pass
        return urls[:500]
    def get_file_links(self,urls):
        files = {}
        for url in urls:
            data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
            files[url] = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', data, re.UNICODE|re.MULTILINE)
            files[url] = files[url][1:]
        return files


class Queues:
    def search_worker(self):
        item = searchQueue.get()
        if (item != ""):
            numFound = Discover().find_available(item)
            if (log == True): print "[*] Found %d entries for %s" % (numFound,item)
            titles = Discover().get_titles(item,numFound)
            if (log == True): print "[*] Found %d titles for %s" % (len(titles),item)
            urls = Discover().get_locations(titles)
            if (log == True): print "[*] Found %d urls for %s" % (len(urls),item)
            files = Discover().get_file_links(urls)
            total = 0
            for url in files.iterkeys():
                                if (total >= 500):
                                        searchQueue.queue.clear()
                                else:
                                        total+=len(files[url])
                                        for file in files[url]:
                                                downloadQueue.put("%s/%s" % (url,file))
                        if (log == True): print "[*] %d files for %s are in the download queue" % (total,item)
                    searchQueue.queue.clear()
        return
    def download_worker(self):
                while True:
                        url = downloadQueue.get()
                        if (url != ""):
                                Obtain().file_download(url)
                        downloadQueue.task_done()

def main():
    #define file types
    itemz = ['pdf','zip', 'tar', 'doc']
    #itemz = ['3g2', '3gp', '3gp2', '3gpp', 'amv', 'asf', 'avi', 'bin', 'divx','drc','dv','f4v','flv','gxf','iso','m1v','m4v','m2t','m2v','mov','mp2','mp2v','mpa'] 
    #drop terms into queue
    for item in itemz:
        searchQueue.put(item)
    #create a bunch of queue threads
    for i in xrange(0,len(itemz)-1):
        t1 = Thread(target=Queues().search_worker(),name="search-%d" % (i)).start()
        t2 = Thread(target=Queues().download_worker(),name="download-%d" % (i)).start()
    sys.exit()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I found a similar problem here: [Python: Unpredictable memory error when downloading large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492797/python-unpredictable-memory-error-when-downloading-large-files)
but when I replace each occurence of read() by read(4096), it still does not work.

Comment: What did you expect to happen when downloading 100k files?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: 100k, you say? It's more like 9 million files.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - I'm just going by the "some hundred thousand entries found for .pdf" in the question. 9 million would be even more too much.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 oh...a mistake. Sry for that info. I think "the houndred thousand" was about another extension. I did not know which it was about anymore. I tried a lot of extensions. PDF was only an example and I know that "the houndred thousand" does not correspond to this extension. Your answers does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to load the details of *every single PDF file* on the Internet Archive into memory at once. As one string. That's a lot of information.

First of all, since it looks like this program is supposed to download all the files, do you even have the *disk space* for *every single* file on there?

Second, if you want to process such a large amount of files, you need to process the data in chunks. As you can see, the API takes parameters called `rows` and `page`. By passing successive values as `page` you can download the information page by page. That way you don't have to have a gigantic JSON string in memory at once, let alone the object structure it deserializes to (which is even bigger).

Additionally I don't think you understand what the parameter to `read()` does if you thought that putting a random number in would somehow "fix" things. If you read in chunks, you need to read multiple times until you get an empty result which signifies the end of the stream.

Edit: Just out of curiosity I tried downloading the JSON and it gave me about one gigabyte before giving up and reporting "Search engine returned invalid information or was unresponsive". I don't think the Archive likes your idea either.

Comment: ok thank you Matti Virkkunen. Your answer is better than that of TIgerhawkT3. I think I am gonna write my own python script to download files by using Scrapy or Beautiful Soup. In that way, I could also learn Web scraping.